# Skipping painful migration with Core Data and move to the new data model

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm spending a lot of time massaging core data into a new migration when I don't even care about the old data. Instead of dealing with the hassle of mapping models each time I change my data model, is there a way to just delete all existing data and jump to the new data model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, just delete the store file and recreate it. I often (at least in development) have my code try an auto migration, and if that fails, blow away the store and start over:

```
// storefile is an NSURL to the store file, mom is the NSManagedObjectModel
NSError *err = nil;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom] autorelease];
[psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                  configuration:nil
                            URL:storefile
                        options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                 NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                 NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                 nil]
                          error:&err];
if (err) // could be more specific about testing this error
{ // assume automigration failed, blow away the store and try again
  err = nil; // log it first!
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storefile
                                            error:nil];
  [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                    configuration:nil
                              URL:storefile
                          options:nil
                            error:&err];
}
// then test err again and give up if there's still a problem
```

Comment: Ah ha, this works, thanks. In development I often just delete the app but in production this isn't a good approach :)

Comment: Did you ship this code without problems? I'm about to submit my app which uses a similar approach.

Comment: Um. I have to admit I did (similar code at least.) The app is such that it can quickly reconstruct its database if it needs to, and letting it do so was quicker+cheaper than setting up mapping models.

Comment: @kukudas I shipped my code using this, and it worked great. I have it look for the 'old' filename, and if it finds it, delete and create a new MOMD. Else, use the existing 'new' MOMD file